# jQuery - divs not fading out completely before next starts fading in

Tags: jquery, fade

The problem is a simple one, I know, but I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure it out. I have 8 divs on a page that hold image galleries which start off hidden. When a user clicks on an icon to view a gallery, the first gallery they chose fades in all shiny. But when they choose another, the one they were viewing begins to fade out while the other fades in below it, and then moves up into its correct position as the first div is hidden.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnTte/7/).

So, my question is apparent:
How do I get the gallery they were viewing to fade out completely before the next one fades into the correct space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place divs on top of each other with `position:absolute;`

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/wnTte/13/

Comment: I don't think the placement of the div is any problem, when he gets his animationproblem solved

Comment: That did it. Thanks, everyone, for playing! I also had to toy around with some of the elements of the gallery, but it's golden! That said, my jQuery is _very_ basic and could probably be cleaned up, but I'm not going to kick a sleeping dog right now.

Comment: @Adam, this hides the problem, it doesn't really solve what is really going on.  Notice that your original color is not fading out first.  Now, if you want a cross-fade, that is a different issue.

Comment: @Jeff B - I'm not switching out colored boxes, but divs, and they're all #000 with a `ul` of images for a gallery.

Comment: @Adam, that's fine.  The same still applies.  Do you want the divs to cross-fade, or do you want one to fade all the way out before the other appears?  If you want cross-fade, then this is generally what you need to do.

Comment: @Jeff B - Actually, the cross-fade is nice. All of the images are the same size, and the gallery images cross-fade, as well. Lends to a unified design. If I wanted to fade to black first, I could have done something like animate or opacity, I suppose.

Comment: @Adam, that's what I figured, but your question specifically says "fade out completely before the next one...".  :)  I don't want you to change your accepted answer, I just wanted to make sure you understood what is going on.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is explained by this sentence in the documentation ([fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)):

> If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

In other words, because you are animating two things, the callback will be called twice.  Because one of your divs is already hidden, the `fadeOut` completes instantly*, and immediately calls back.

**Instantly completing if already shown/hidden is unique to the show/hide type helper functions.  If you constructed your own fade animation it would always take the specified amount of time, regardless of the current state.*

You can fix this a couple of ways.  The easiest is to chain your `fadeOut()` calls inside of each other, instead of calling one on both elements:

```
$('.icon_one').click(function() {
    $('#image_two').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#image_three').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#image_one').fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Because one will usually be hidden already, it will fall through instantly, but the other will take time.  Either way, only after both are complete will the fade in happen.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/XQnhs/

Of course, with a little change to your HTML, you can do all three with **one** click handler:

```
<div id="image_one" class="imageBox" style="background-color:red;height:50px;width:50px">&nbsp;</div>  
<div id="image_two" class="imageBox" style="background-color:blue;height:50px;width:50px">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="image_three" class="imageBox" style="background-color:yellow;height:50px;width:50px">&nbsp;</div>

<div data-num="one" class="icon_show">Red</div>
<div data-num="two" class="icon_show">Blue</div>
<div data-num="three" class="icon_show">Yellow</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.icon_show').click(function() {
    var showID = '#image_' + $(this).data('num');
    $('.imageBox:visible').fadeOut(function() {
        $(showID).fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/NAcPW/

The key being that you automatically figure out which one to show based on the link you click.  In this case, I do it by storing a number in a data attribute.  You could also just use part of the ID, or do it by figuring out the offset using `index` and then feeding that into `eq`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/NnN58/

There are lots of ways to simplify this code.

Answer (score 3):

This was interesting... I like the way you set up your jsfiddle- it made it easier to play around with. see if this helps.. fadeOuts are bound to more than element. Only fade out the visible one. I think your issue is fadeout is getting called on elements that already faded out.

here is a slight variation on your jsfiddle..

```
$(function(){
        $('#image_two,#image_three').hide();

//1//       

          $('.icon_one').click(function(){                
              $('#image_two:visible,#image_three:visible').fadeOut(
                  function(){

                     $('#image_one').fadeIn();
                  }
              );
           });

//2//
alert("binding");
   $('.icon_two').click(function(){
       $('#image_one:visible,#image_three:visible').fadeOut(
            function(){
                $('#image_two').fadeIn();
             }
                                            );
  });

    //3//

   $('.icon_three').click(function(){
       $('#image_one:visible,#image_two:visible').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#image_three').fadeIn();
        });
  });

});
```

Comment: The problem here is that the `icon_#` are menu elements, and the user can click any of the elements, so the `$('#...,#...,#...')fadeOut` covers all of the possible visible elements.

Comment: hey Adam... i really think the issue is items that are already faded out- but there are probably multiple ways to get it working.

Comment: The problem remains: Which item is visible? How to determine that? In this sense, fade out all items to fade out the one that's visible. I imagine an 'if/then' scenario might have taken care of this, but it's a bit out of my wheelhouse right now.

Comment: I hear you-- it's all about the selectors. I imagine you could class all of the images do do something like  $(".slideshow:visible") where only one should be visible at a time. good luck-- it was a very good question.

Answer (score 1):

how about replacing

```
$('#image_one').fadeIn();
```

with

```
$('#image_one').delay(500).fadeIn();
```

and like wise....

Comment: Fine, if you're dealing with one div.