# How to way load the next image before the previous one fades out totally in jquery slideshow?

Tags: jquery, background, slideshow, fadein

I have a slideshow and I would like to have the next image fadeIn as the current image fades out.

So, is there anyway way to load the next image before the previous one fades out totally?

This is what I am using:

```
    var aImages = new Array();
    var iPrev = -1;
    var iRnd = -1;
    aImages[0] = "01.jpg";
    aImages[1] = "02.jpg";
    aImages[2] = "03.jpg";
    aImages[3] = "04.jpg";
    aImages[4] = "05.jpg";
    aImages[5] = "06.jpg";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img#bg").load(function()
            {
                $("img#bg").fadeTo(2000,1);
                setTimeout(function() 
                    {
                        $("img#bg").fadeOut(1000);
                        setTimeout(LoadImages,1000);
                    }
                    ,4000);
            }           
        )
        setTimeout(LoadImages,1000);
});
function LoadImage(iNr)
    {
        $("img#bg").attr("src", aImages[iNr]);      
};    
function LoadImages()
{
    while(iPrev == iRnd)
    {
        iRnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*aImages.length);
    }
    LoadImage(iRnd);
    iPrev = iRnd;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-load the images using Javascript as shown in [this article](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jpreload.htm)

Comment: Ok, I've tried that and then? Are supposed to fade into each other automatically immediately if I will preload the images? Another thing I am curious about, in the script I am using, am I not preloading the images in that array already?!

Answer (score 0):

Working link: http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/wnTte/13/
Just put images on top of each other.

was an answer to below question but may work for you too

[jQuery - divs not fading out completely before next starts fading in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110749/jquery-divs-not-fading-out-completely-before-next-starts-fading-in)

Comment: I already have everything in place, I was just looking to modify the above code instead of implementing some other solution.